# Exercises in Quotient spaces for collapsing a set to a point with modified definition.

Tags: general-topology

I found two different slightly definitions for the concept of collapsing a set to a point.  For the second block quote with the displayed exercise, I am cnofuse over the wording of 19 (a).  I don't understand the sentence "$q$ restricts to a homeomorphism $q:X\setminus{A}\rightarrow q(X\setminus{A})$ of the subspaces $X\setminus{A}\subset X$ and $q(X\setminus{A})\subset X/A.$"  I am wondering if someone can elaborate or rephrase what is asking.  Also, for part (b), under what condition might $q$ be not a homeomorphism.
Finally, are these two questions are consequences when discussing collapsing a set to a point if we imposed closedness on the set compare with the definition included in the first blockquote?

From text Topology by Murray Eisenberg, definition from pg 250

> Let $A$ be a nonempty closed subset of a topological space $X$. Define $\text{~}$ to be the equivalence relation on $X$ that identifies all points of $A$ with each other:  $x\text{~}y$ $\text{iff}$ $(x=y)$ or $\text{($x \in A$ and  $y \in A)$}$.  Then the points of the quotient set $X/\text{~}$ are the singletons $\{x\}$ for $x$ not in $A$ together with the distinguished point $A$. (note that $\text{$A=a/\text{~} \in X/\text{~}$ for each $a\in A$})$  The quotient space $x\text{~}$, sometimes denoted by $X/A$, is said to be obtained by $\mathit{\text{collapsing $A$ to a point}}$.

From text An Introduction to Topology and Homotopy by Allan Sieradski, definition from pg 150, and exercise as exercise 19. from pg 170

> For any subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, there is the equivalence relation, $\text{~}_A$ defined by
>
> $\quad\text{$x\text{~}_A z$ if and only if either $x=z$ or $\{x,z\}\subset A.$}\\$
> The quotient space of $X$ modulo $\text{~}_A$ is denoted by $X/A$ and is called the $\mathbf{\mathit{\text{quotient space of $X$ modulo $A$}}};$ it is a topological version of $X$ in which the subset $A$ is collapsed to a single point $[A].$  The quotient map is denoted by $q_A:X\rightarrow X/A.$  The open subsets $V\subset X/A$ have the form $V=q_A(U)\subset X/A,$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and either $U\subset X-A$ or $A\subset U$
> [From  Chapter 5 exercises of text]
> Let $q:X\rightarrow (X/A)$ be the quotient map that collapses a subspace $A\in X$ to a point.
> (a) Prove that when the subspace $A$ is closed in X, $q$ restricts to a homeomorphism $q:X\setminus{A}\rightarrow q(X\setminus{A})$ of the subspaces $X\setminus{A}\subset X$ and $q(X\setminus{A})\subset X/A$
> (b) Show that the restriction $q:X\setminus{A}\rightarrow q(X\setminus{A})$ may not be a homeomorphism.
> (c) Show that, for any space $Y$, the continuous functions $X\rightarrow Y$ that are constant on $A$ are in bijective correspondence with the continuous functions $X\setminus{A}\subset X$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both definitions agree on how the quotient map is defined and what the quotient set $X{/}A$ looks like: all $$X{/}A=\{\{x\}: x \in X\setminus A\} \cup \{A\}$$ the set of equivalence classes, and $$q(x) = \begin{cases} \{x\} & x \notin A\\
A & x \in A\end{cases}$$

The topology on $X{/}A$ is defined as always for a quotient:

$$O \subseteq X{/}A \text{ open } \iff q^{-1}[O] \subseteq X \text{ open}$$

Now, for all $A \subseteq X$ we have that $q\restriction_{X\setminus A} \to q[X\setminus A]$ is a bijection (essentially a map between points $x$ and their one-point class $\{x\}$) that is continuous (restrictions of continuous maps are still continuous), but for $A$ closed we can say that $q$ is also an open map ($O \subseteq X\setminus A$ open implies $O$ open in $X$ ("open in open is open") and $q^{-1}[q[O]]=O$ so $q[O]$ is open by the above definition of the quotient topology. Similarly we can show that if $A$ is open, $q$ will be a closed map and it is standard that a continuous bijection that is open (or closed) is a homeomorphism. This shows the first claim of the final quote.

To see 2. we need to look for an example where we do not identify a closed set (nor an open one), so try $A=\Bbb Q$ in $X=\Bbb R$ (usual topology). Then $O=\mathbb{P}\cap (0,1)$ is open in $X\setminus A$ (the irrationals, also denoted by $\Bbb P$) while $q[O]=\{\{x\}: x \in \Bbb P\}$ is not open in $q[\Bbb P]$, because that would mean there is a set $U \subseteq X{/}A$ such that $U \cap q[\Bbb P]=q[O]$, but the only new point of $U$ can then be $A$ but then $q^{-1}[U]$ would not be open in $\Bbb R$ (containing, as it does, lots of rationals outside $(0,1)$, that are not interior points, and so $U$ could not have been open). So the restricted $q$ is not open and so not a homeomorphism.

For 3. , which is IMHO unclearly formulated, note that for each $f:X \to Y$ that is constant on $A$ (so $f[A]=\{p\}$ for some $p \in Y$) we have a well defined $\hat{f}: X{/}A \to Y$ defined by $\hat{f}(\{x\})= f(x)$ when $x \notin A$ and $\hat{f}(A)=p$ and this obeys $\hat{f} \circ q=f$, which implies that $\hat{f}$ is continuous if $f$ is. And when $g: X{/}A \to Y$ is a function, define $\mu(g): X \to Y$ by $\mu(g)(x)=g(\{x\})$ if $x \notin A$ and $\mu(g)(x)=g(A)$ for $x \in A$, which is well-defined. And as sets of functions we thus always have a bijection between $$\{f: X \to Y: |f[A]|=1\} \text { and } \{\hat{f}\mid \hat{f}:X{/}A \to Y\}$$

and continuity is preserved too from $f$ to $\hat{f}$, while for continuity of $g$ from $\mu(g)$ we could use that this holds when $A$ is closed or open again.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient map q:X -> X/A is a homeormorphism.
S = X - A is a subspace of X.
q$_S$, the restriction of q to S, is the map q$_S$:S -> X/A, x -> q(x).
q$_S$ maps S onto X/A - {A} which is a subspace of X/A.

For b, let X be the real line and A the set of rationals.

Comment: can I ask if for part b, is it stating that $q$ being restricted to $S$ might not be a homeomorphism if the subspace $A$ is not a closed set?

Comment: @SethMai.  See edit.